# jQuery Mobile PhotoSwipe: undefined in not a function

Tags: jquery-mobile, photoswipe

I'm trying to setup a simple example of jQuery Mobile PhotoSwipe:

http://codepen.io/aherrick/pen/pvEsn

I keep getting this error both locally and on CodePen.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in PhotoSwipe file `code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.11.js`, line `4741`:

```
$(thumbEls).live('click', function(e){
```

[As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/), and it seems you are using jQuery 1.7.1. To fix the problem you should replace the line with:

```
$(document).on('click', 'thumbEls', function(e){
```

However, the problem seems to be PhotoSwipe integration with jQuery Mobile. I've made many tests, and it seems like PhotoSwipe doesn't work with the latest version of jQuery and jQuery Mobile. As you can see from this minimal code sample, latest PhotoSwipe works with jQuery `1.5.2` and JQM `1.0a4.1`. If I update those libraries PhotoSwipe stops working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://photoswipe.com/latest/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <link href="http://photoswipe.com/latest/photoswipe.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
        div.gallery-row:after { clear: both; content: "."; display: block; height: 0; visibility: hidden; }
        div.gallery-item { float: left; width: 33.333333%; }
        div.gallery-item a { display: block; margin: 5px; border: 1px solid #3c3c3c; }
        div.gallery-item img { display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; }
        #Gallery1 .ui-content, #Gallery2 .ui-content { overflow: hidden; }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://photoswipe.com/latest/lib/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://photoswipe.com/latest/lib/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://photoswipe.com/latest/lib/simple-inheritance.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://photoswipe.com/latest/lib/jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://photoswipe.com/latest/code-photoswipe-jQuery-1.0.8.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="gallery" class="gallery-page">
    <div data-role="content">       
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a></div>
            <div class="gallery-item"><a href="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/Cxagv.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("div.gallery a").photoSwipe();        
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey I've made that change and the error has gone away but I'm still not seeing the swipe functionality work

Comment: can you create a new CodePen with the updated plugin?

Comment: ...it seems there is nothing to do: PhotoSwipe works only with obsolete libraries :-(